# JQuery Function Success Not Launching New View With Syncfusion Datagrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, syncfusion

I have an MVC4 application that uses a Syncfusion Datagrid.  On the view I have a button  (xfrButton) that executes a jquery function:

```
            $(document).ready(function () {

            // Handle the clicking of the Request Transfer button
            $('#xfrButton').click(function () {

                // Initialize object to hold data grid
                var GridObj = $find("AssetGrid")

                // Initialize object to hold the filters the user selected in the grid
                var gridData = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(GridObj._filters);

                // Call controller action to process selected filters passing the filters variable (gridData)
                $.post('<%: ResolveUrl("~/Step05_AssetsValidBUActiveCRS/RequestToTransfer/")%>', { select: gridData },
                                    function (data) {

                                        // If successful, call the Transfer Request View
                                        var targetModel = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(data);
                                        var targetURL = '~/Step05_TransferRequest/Index/?transferVM=' + targetModel.toString();
//                                        var targetURL = '~/Step05_TransferRequest/Index/';

                                        //TODO:  Figure out a way to launch a new view upon success return from above statement
                                        //       Must pass the data returned from the above .post to the new controller action
                                        //       Current process just stays on the existing screen.  Neither of the following work:

                                        $(this).load(targetModel);
//                                        window.location.href(targetURL);
                                    }
                    , "json")

            })

        })
```

The call to /Step05_AssetsValidBUActiveCRS/RequestToTransfer in the .post works like a charm and the data returned is a viewmodel that contains the data for the next view that I want to launch.  The only problem is that no matter what I try to do to launch the next view/action (in this case the URL in targetURL), the current view and datagrid remains in place in the browser.

I can click the xfrButton button again and it fires the above routine which does the .post action again but still doesn't fire the targetURL value.  Why wouldn't the jquery launch the new view?

For reference, here is the Syncfusion code in the view along with the button:

```
   <p>
        <input id="xfrButton" type="submit" value="Request Transfer To" />
   </p>

<%=Html.Syncfusion().Grid<AMSUtilityMVC4.ViewModels.Step05ListAssetsValidBUActiveCRSViewModel>("AssetGrid")
    .Datasource(Model)
    .EnableFiltering()      /*Filtering Enabled*/
    .EnableSorting()        /*Sorting Enabled*/
    .EnablePaging()         /*Paging Enabled*/
    .AllowResizing(true)
    .Scrolling(scroll => scroll.Height(300).Width(1050))
    .EnableScrolling()
    .AllowSelection(true).RowsSelectionMode(RowsSelectionMode.Toggle)
    .Column(cols =>
    {
        cols.Add(c => c.REMS).HeaderText("REMS").Width(75);
        cols.Add(c => c.companyName).HeaderText("Company").Width(150);
        cols.Add(c => c.LVID).HeaderText("LVID").Width(75);
        cols.Add(c => c.entity).HeaderText("BU").Width(75);
        cols.Add(c => c.locationDescription).HeaderText("Location Description").Width(150);            
        cols.Add(c => c.assetNumber).HeaderText("Asset No").Width(100);
        cols.Add(c => c.majorCategory).HeaderText("Major Cat").Width(150);
        cols.Add(c => c.minorCategory).HeaderText("Minor Cat").Width(150);
        cols.Add(c => c.FACode).HeaderText("FA Code").Width(75);
        cols.Add(c => c.description).HeaderText("Title").Width(150);
        cols.Add(c => c.cost).HeaderText("Cost").TextAlign(Syncfusion.Mvc.Grid.TextAlignment.Right).Format("{0:C}").Width(70);
        cols.Add(c => c.nbv).HeaderText("NBV").Width(60);
        cols.Add(c => c.GOC).HeaderText("GOC").Width(75);
        cols.Add(c => c.FEIN).HeaderText("FEIN").Width(75);
        cols.Add(c => c.datePlacedInService).HeaderText("In Service").Width(150);
        cols.Add(c => c.vendorName).HeaderText("Vendor Name").Width(150);
        cols.Add(c => c.accountingKey).HeaderText("Acct Key").Width(150);           
        cols.Add(c => c.locationKey).HeaderText("Location Key").Width(150);
        cols.Add(c => c.state).HeaderText("State");
    })
    .ClientSideEvents(e => e.OnToolbarClickEvent("OnToolbarClickEvent"))
    .ToolBar(tools =>
    {
        // Adding the custom toolbar items. 
        // Add(customItemtitle, customItemcaption, customItemCssClass)                   
        tools.Add(GridToolBarItems.ExcelExport, "Excel Export")
            .Add(GridToolBarItems.PDFExport, "PDF Export")
            .Add(GridToolBarItems.Custom, "Transfer Request To", "RequestTransfer");
    })
    .Mappers(map =>{map.ExportExcelAction("GridExportToExcel")
                        .ExportPdfAction("GridExportToPDF");}) 
%>
```

Comment: instead of using `$(this).load(targetModel)` try using `$("correctselector").load(targetURL)`. if it is whole page use $(document.documentElement) as selector

Answer (score 0):

```
Your requirement can be solved by passing targetURL in load function. Please refer to the following code snippets:

[JavaScript]

function OnToolbarClickEvent(sender, args) {
    var GridObj = sender;
    if (args._currentItem.title == "RequestToTransfer") {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/RequestToTransfer",
            data:
                    {
                        "select": Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(GridObj._filters)
                    },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                var targetModel = Sys.Serialization.`JavaScriptSerializer`.serialize(data);
                var targetURL = '/Home/RequestToTransfer/?select=' + targetModel.toString();
                //                                        var targetURL = '~/Step05_TransferRequest/Index/';

                //TODO:  Figure out a way to launch a new view upon success return from above statement
                //       Must pass the data returned from the above .post to the new controller action
                //       Current process just stays on the existing screen.  Neither of the following work:

                $(this).load(targetURL); // pass target URl to load
            }
        });
    }
}

[Controller]

  public ActionResult RequestToTransfer(string select)
        {
            var data = OrderRepository.GetAllRecords();`enter code here`
            ViewData["data"] = data.Take(10).ToList();
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);      // returns data in success`enter code here`enter code here`
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting the silly mistake I had in my question.  How do I pass the serialized model data to the controller with the .load statement?